# set iOS status bar text color to black

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

On one of my `viewControllers` I'm setting the NavigationBar programatically (to White with Black tint color)

All is well, but the text of the statusBar stays white (therefore not visible)

The code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `navigationBar.titleTextAttributes` and set title color and font.

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor redColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Comment: I'm getting deprecation warnings...

Anyway - I tried - 
NSDictionary *titleAttrs = self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes;
[titleAttrs setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"NSForegroundColorAttributeName"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttrs];

And it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
```

Did the trick...